# can not recognize the property of a variable while using the nodemailer module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a mailer through the node.js nodemailer module.

I created mails as arrays, and I created properties for each array through an object literal.

And when I started Mailer, I was having trouble recognizing `mailList[i].name`.

What's wrong with my code?

**mailer code**

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "test@gmail.com",
      pass: "123456"
    }
  });

  let mails = ["test1@gmail.com", "test2@gmail.com"];

  let mailList = {
    "mails[1]": {
      name: "Tom",
    },
    "mails[2]": {
      name: "Lexy",
    }
  };

  let go = () => {
    for (let i = 1; i < 30; i++) {
      let setting = {
        from: "test@gmail.com",
        to: mails[i],
        subject: "Title",
        text: ` Hi, ${mailList[i].name}`
      };
    }
  };

  transporter.sendMail(go(), (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your `mails` variable is a string array, it does not contain any object attribute called `name`. And in your loop you would want to start from 0 as javascript arrays are zero indexed.

Comment: `mailList` is an object not an array, To be able to access it with `mailList[i].name` you should change the definition. ```let mailList = [
    {
      name: "Tom",
    },
    {
      name: "Lexy",
    }
  ];```

Comment: I want to store the mail in mails and store the mail owner's information in the mailList.

Answer (score 0):

The problem there, is that you are calling `mailList[i].name` and `i` will never be a valid index for that object. Instead, you should do:

```
let setting = {
    from: "test@gmail.com",
    to: mails[i],
    subject: "Title",
    text: ` Hi, ${mailList["mails[" + i + "]"].name}`
};
```

But here, I would like to make a suggestion. Why use two structures, when you could easily this data in an array of objects? Then, your code would become:

```
nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "test@gmail.com",
      pass: "123456"
    }
  });

  let mails = [
    {
      name: "Tom",
      email: "test1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      name: "Tom",
      email: "test1@gmail.com"
    }
  ]

  let go = () => {
    for (const mail of mails) {
      let setting = {
        from: "test@gmail.com",
        to: mail.email,
        subject: "Title",
        text: ` Hi, ${mail.name}`
      };
    }
  };

  transporter.sendMail(go(), (error, response) => {
    if (error) {
      return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log(response);
  });
});
```

This way, you fit all the information of the contact into a single object, instead of having pieces of it all around your code.

Comment: "Error: No recipients defined" has occurred.

Answer (score -1):

```js
nodemailer.createTestAccount((err, account) => {
  let transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    auth: {
      user: "test@gmail.com",
      pass: "123456"
    }
  });

  let mails = [
    {
      name: "Tom",
      email: "test1@gmail.com"
    },
    {
      name: "Tom",
      email: "test1@gmail.com"
    }
  ]

  let go = () => {
    for (const mail of mails) {
      let setting = {
        from: "test@gmail.com",
        to: mail.email,
        subject: "Title",
        text: ` Hi, ${mail.name}`
      };
      
      //validate setting object is set correctly before calling the sendMail method
        transporter.sendMail(setting, (error, response) => {
          if (error) {
            return console.log(error);
          }
          console.log(response);
        });
    }
  };

go();

});
```

Comment: I still get "TypeError: Can not read property 'name' of undefined".

Comment: This is because your `mailist` array length is less than the length of the loop in your `go()` method, once it goes past the second value, it returns undefined. You can add a check to see it does not boom out at that index.

Comment: Oh! Thank you. I followed your words. But I get the error "ReferenceError: mails is not defined". haha ...

Comment: It works for me.. I have updated the answer. You should check your configuration properly. Kindly remove the `console.log` if you are happy to copy the code

Comment: It works through "go ();" but still produces "Error: No recipients defined" in "transporter.sendMail (go, ...)".

Comment: I have updated my answer... You are trying to send an array through `sendmailer` protocol, but this accepts one object at a time.. Moved the send method into the loop. should send through now.

Comment: Thank you for your continued interest. I modified the code, but I get "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded".

Comment: I think it's not right to pass "go ()" as an argument to sendMail. So I tried changing "go ()" to "go". No stack errors occurred at this time, but "Error: No recipients defined" appeared.

Comment: I have updated the code, you were supposed to pass the setting object into the `sendmailer` protocol.  I skipped it completely.. Fixed now